# Oslo Airport COVID Test Time

Tags: paperwork, covid-19, norway

I'm potentially going to need to travel to Norway from the UK to undertake some work on a customer site.

I think I'd need to quarantine for either 10 days or until I get a test.

I've seen that there is now a test centre at Oslo airport but I've not been able to find out how long it takes to get a result from here.

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Do they recognise a UK test you could get shortly before departing?

Comment: @gerrit IF the OP can get one. Private tests are hard to find, unless you live in London, based on my recent experience. Booking well in advance (2 months, in my case) is advisable.

Comment: @Traveller Oh, interesting.  Here they're available on a day's notice (at own expense).

Comment: @gerrit Private self-swab home tests are more easily available and cheaper than in-clinic tests (latter around £195), results should be within 48hrs of the lab receiving the specimen. Getting a valid test certificate if travelling on a Sunday or Monday might prove problematic due to processing timescales, AFAIK

Comment: @gerrit COVID tests are worthless in Norway in the first place, so the question is moot

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly informed and so the question is moot. A COVID-19 test is worthless in Norway. You **will** need to self-isolate, but it's very lax: you can go out but must keep distance from those you're not staying with, and for border control you'll need a printed accommodation confirmation for your whole stay (up to 10 days). Also, use public transport for getting to/from the airport only (with a face covering, otherwise not needed).

SOURCE: § 5 of the COVID-19 regulation (in Norwegian) https://lovdata.no/dokument/SF/forskrift/2020-03-27-470

Comment: I'd be travelling for work. It's not really a matter of getting caught, it's a matter of being seen to comply with regulations.

What's the purpose of the testing at the airport if you'd have to isolate anyway?

Comment: @Persistence The test is for your own reassurance basically. But again, to follow the regulations strictly: only use public transport to/from the airport (with a face covering, otherwise not required), and keep distance when going outside. That's it

Comment: @Persistence Added a source (paragraph 5 of the relevant regulation)